# Using mean value theorem and Rolle's theorem to prove an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

$f$ is a continuous function on 
${[}0,+\infty{)}$ and differentiable on ${(}0,+\infty{)}$, and $f$ is strictly decreasing on ${(}0,+\infty{)}$

the question is: is this inequality true for each $ $ $(a,b)$ $ $ $\in ({[}0,+\infty{)})^2$ $ $ such as $ $ $a<b$ $:$

$(b-a)f(b)\leqslant f(b)-f(a) \leqslant (b-a)f(a)$

I've tried to prove that $ \forall x \in {[}a,b{]} $ : $f(b)\leqslant f'(x)\leqslant f(a)$ so I can apply the mean value theorem
on   ${[}a,b{]}$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: What you tried to prove is not true in general. Let $f(x)=-x$. Take $b=4$ and $a=3$ so you try to prove: $-4 \leq -1 \leq -3$, which is wrong!

Comment: Aaaand that is also your counterexample...for the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments. It is not true. Take $f(x)=-x$, $b=4$ and $a=3$ you have: $f(b)-f(a)= -4+3 = -1$ and $f(a)=f(3)=-3$ but $-1 > -3$ so it is not TRUE that $f(b)-f(a)\leq (b-a) f(a)$.

Comment: oh I see thanks . 
can you help me more ? an indication maybe  ?

Comment: You see that is not true with that example. What do you mean by an indication exactly?

Comment: thanks , I get it now .